# Previous content of partial view not deleting after return from ajax call

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to update partialview after ajax call, the partial view is updating but the previous content not deleted from screen.
I have now the prevoious one and the current results on the screen.
That's my code:

```
 public ActionResult FindMovies(string text)
    {
        ViewBag.ShowButton = Rented;
        FindMovie(text);
        if (movies.Count == 0)
            ViewBag.Movies = "null";
        else
            ViewBag.Movies = "notNull";

        return View(movies);

    }
    public ActionResult Rent(int id)
    {
        if (Rented.Equals("no"))
        {
            movieRent = db.Movies.Find(id);
            movieRent.UserRent = userId;
            movieRent.Rented = true;
            db.Entry(movieRent).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            Rented = "yes";
            movies.Find(x => x.ID == id).UserRent = userId;
            movies.Find(x => x.ID == id).Rented = true;
        }
        return PartialView("MovieList", movies);


    }
```

That's the view:

```
 <div class="center">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("MovieList", Model);}
    </div>
```

and its the partialview:

```
  @model IEnumerable<MvcMovies.Models.Movies>

<ul class="result">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <figure>
                            <img src="@Url.Content(@item.Path)"
                                 width="100" height="100" alt="movie logo" />
                        </figure>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <article>
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                            </div>
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year)
                            </div>

                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StageManager)
                            </div>

                            <div class="editor-label">

                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ganre)
                            </div>

                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Summary)
                            </div>

                            <div class="rent" id="rent">
                                @if (item.Rented.Equals(true))
                                {
                                    <label>Rented</label>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Rent",
                        "Rent",
                        "Subscription",
                          new { id = item.ID },
                          new AjaxOptions()
                        {
                            UpdateTargetId = "rent",
                            OnComplete = "onAjaxComplete",
                            HttpMethod = "post",
                        })

                                }

                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </li>
    }


</ul>
```

Thanks.